# Printing for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

The problem I am having is related to the output from for loops. I currently have 3 of them and get the following output:

```
t
t
t
p
p
p
s
s
s
```

The output I am shooting for is:

```
t,p,s
t,p,s
t,p,s
```

Here is the sample code

```
# Outputs First Product
title_print = print(title[0].text.strip())
price_print = print(price[0].text.strip())
shipping_print = print(shipping[0].text.strip())

# Outputs All Products
for t in title:
    print(t.text.strip())

for p in price:
    print(p.text.strip())

for s in shipping:
    print(s.text.strip())
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try not to use for in/for each but iterate using the indizes one time(with only one loop).

Comment: consider using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip): `for t,p,s in zip(title, price, shipping): print(t, p, s)`

Comment: @dan1st Thanks for the tip! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for t,p,s in zip(title, price, shipping):
    print(f"{t.text.strip()}, {p.text.strip()}, {s.text.strip()}")
```